# What is wrong with my syntax when trying to solve the following system?

Tags: equation-solving

Why doesn't Mathematica return $k=1$ for the following system of equations?

```
 Solve[{x + (k + 1) y - 3 + k == 0,  x + 2y - 2 == 0}, k]
```

But, instead, it gives an empty output `{ }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Solve >>  Possible Issues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html);

> - Solve *gives generic solutions; solutions involving equations on parameters are not given*

You can:

> - *Use the* Exists *quantifier to find solutions that are valid for some value of parameter(s)*:

```
Solve[Exists[x, x + (k + 1) y - 3 + k == 0 && x + 2 y - 2 == 0], k]
```

> {{k -> 1}}

or the option `MaxExtraConditions`:

> - *With* MaxExtraConditions->All, Solve *also gives non-generic solutions:*

```
Solve[{x + (k + 1) y - 3 + k == 0, x + 2 y - 2 == 0}, k, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

> Solve::fdimc: When parameter values satisfy the condition y==-1&&x==4, the solution set contains a full-dimensional component; use Reduce for complete solution information.
>
> {{k -> ConditionalExpression[1, -2 + x + 2 y == 0 && y != -1]}}

Alternatively, you can use `Reduce`:

> - Reduce *gives all solutions, including those that require equations on parameters:*

```
Reduce[{x + (k + 1) y - 3 + k == 0, x + 2 y - 2 == 0}, k]
```

> (y == -1 && x == 4) || (x == -2 (-1 + y) && 1 + y != 0 && k == 1)

Or `Solve` for `{k,x}` or `{k,y}`:

```
Solve[{x + (k + 1) y - 3 + k == 0, x + 2 y - 2 == 0}, {k, x}]
```

> {{k -> 1, x -> -2 (-1 + y)}}